# Select Rows Where MultiIndex Is In Another DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have one DataFrame (DF1) with a MultiIndex and many additional columns. In another DataFrame (DF2) I have 2 columns containing a set of values from the MultiIndex. I would like to select the rows from DF1 where the MultiIndex matches the values in DF2.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 3, 4, 7, 10],
                    'year': [2012, 2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
                    'sale':[55, 17, 40, 84, 31]})

df1 = df1.set_index(['year','month'])

            sale
year  month
2012  1     55
2012  3     17
2014  4     40
2013  7     84
2014  10    31

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2012,2014],
                    'month': [1, 10]})

   year  month  
0  2012   1
1  2014   10
```

I'd like to create a new DataFrame that would be:

```
                 sale
year    month
2012    1        55
2014    10       31
```

I've tried many variations using .isin, .loc, slicing, but keep running into errors.

Comment: cant you select the rows before setting the index?

Answer (score 2):

You could just `set_index` on `df2` the same way and pass the index:

```
In[110]:
df1.loc[df2.set_index(['year','month']).index]

Out[110]: 
            sale
year month      
2012 1        55
2014 10       31
```

more readable version:

```
In[111]:
idx = df2.set_index(['year','month']).index
df1.loc[idx]

Out[111]: 
            sale
year month      
2012 1        55
2014 10       31
```

Comment: This seems to narrow down the rows as expected, however all of the columns show up as Nan. Does the order of the index matter? The index in df2 is a different order from df1 in my actual dataset.

Comment: You'll need to post raw data, code to reproduce your dfs, and this erroneous result in your question as it's impossible to answer otherwise